# How do you do a SQL update a table using a group by function, and length filter?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to update specific records within two columns by filtering on the length of the column as well as the max of a third column to grab the latest record. I'm aware that I can't use a group by function like this, and have been trying to figure out how to do it using a sub query.

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET COLUMN1 = 'NULL', COLUMN2 = 'NULL'
WHERE LENGTH (COLUMN1) BETWEEN 10 AND 20
AND MAX (COLUMN3)


SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE LENGTH(COL1) BETWEEN 10 AND 20
AND MAX(COLUMN3)
```

This returns what I want, for example purposes. Their are two columns within the table that I want to set specific rows with a specific length to null, also filtered with the max function to grab the latest record.

Comment: You can group, as long as you flatten the resultset in a subquery and join to that in the update query

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry you're correct, the from was from when I was testing to see if I could grab the data in a select. Removed 'FROM', from the update query.

Comment: What do you mean by `AND MAX (COLUMN3)`?

Comment: `"This returns what I want"`. Really? `AND MAX(COLUMN3)` should produce a syntax error. I doubt this is what you want.

Comment: Please show us some sample data, so we understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want this:

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET COLUMN1 = 'NULL', COLUMN2 = 'NULL'
    WHERE LENGTH(COLUMN1) BETWEEN 10 AND 20 AND
          COLUMN3 = (SELECT MAX(t2.COLUMN3)
                     FROM TABLE t2
                     WHERE LENGTH(t2.COLUMN1) BETWEEN 10 AND 20
                    );
```

Also, why are you setting the columns to the string `'NULL'`?  If you want a `NULL` value then drop the single quotes.

Comment: Is it possible to get the results of this query by writing it like so `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE LENGTH(COLUMN1) BETWEEN 10 AND 20 AND
          COLUMN3 = (SELECT MAX(t2.COLUMN3)
                     FROM TABLE t2
                     WHERE LENGTH(t2.COLUMN1) BETWEEN 10 AND 20
                    );`

Comment: @Danny . . . Yes, that should return the rows that will be updated.

Comment: The records being updated are normally encrypted , for documentation purposes we put the word NULL in its place if it was not encrypted so we know their was a record there originally.